Stateflow: implement an interruptuble timer
Problem
I want to create a stateflow chart that triggers a controller (enabled/function-call subsystem) every 100ms. However, if certain conditions are met during the intermediate time between controller runs, the controller must be called and afterwards, the timer must be resetted.    (Reset the controller)
I've tried to make an simplified version of the above, however it does not work as expected.

The controller is not activated every 100ms.
After resetting, the controller is left in an activated state, while i want the activation to be just for a timestep. (the outport of the function-call subsystem resets to zero when disabed).

Current program

Where the stateflow chart (Controller Governor) is the following:

What i get is (vs what i expect to get is the following):

Background and general goal
I am trying to simulate an MPC controller (which i intent to port to ros) in simscape. The weights and setpoints of the MPC change depending on its current position in the workspace. I want to create "interrupting" logic that detects if i should change the weights of the MPC based on the current position.
In cpp the above could be achieved with a similar code:
ros::Timer timer = nh.createTimer(ros::Duration(0.1), run_controller);
while(ros::ok()){
    resetting = check_reseting_conditions();
    if (resetting==true){
        run_controller();
        timer.reset();
    }
}


In the options for your function() subsystem I think either the output port or the trigger block will have an option to "hold" or "reset" the output state when the subsystem is not enabled, do you have them set to reset?
